# Center divs with fixed height and width horizontally in a responsive webpage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a bunch of divs with text in them (`aboutMeDescriptionItem` sub-div in `aboutMeDescriptionItemListList`), they need to be horizontally centered. As in - even if I reduce the browser width, they need to be centered.

```css
#secondPageContainer {
  font-family: "San Francisco - Ultra Light";
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(44, 62, 80,1.0);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 0;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh; 
}
#aboutMe {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#aboutMeTitle {
  font-size: 5em;
}
#aboutMeSubtitle {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
#aboutMeDescription {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
#aboutMeDescriptionBasic {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96,1.0);
}
#aboutMeDescriptionBasic h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
}
#aboutMeDescriptionItemList {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.aboutMeDescriptionItem {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96,1.0);
}
.aboutMeDescriptionItem h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondPageContainer">
  <div id="aboutMe">
    <h2 id="aboutMeTitle">About Me</h2>
    <h4 id="aboutMeSubtitle">Get to know me better</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutMeDescription">
    <div id="aboutMeDescriptionBasic">
      <h3> Something about me... </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper">
      <div id="aboutMeDescriptionItemList">
        <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
          <!--h3>bla bla.</h3-->
        </div>
        <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
          <!--h3>bla bla bla.</h3-->
        </div>
        <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
          <!--h3>Bla bla bla bla bla something really long.</h3--></div>
        <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
          <!--h3>Bla bla bla bla bla something really even longer..</h3-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Right now I face two problems:**

1. Leaving the text commented. The `aboutMeDescriptionItemList` is not aligned to the center of `aboutMeDescriptionItemWrapper`. When the window is resized to smaller size, the last box (`aboutMeDescriptionItem`) is moved below as expected, but it is not centered, instead it floats to the left.
2. If the text is un-commented the box's top line (origin) is aligned to the text header `h3`. Which renders the boxes on different origins due to different `h3` content sizes.

**Example:** I want the boxes to align like the "And, here's the HASHTAG team" page (4th page). http://hashtagposters.strikingly.com/

Comment: Try adding `text-align: center;` to `#aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper` might help - https://jsfiddle.net/e6oegoc0/

Comment: OH MY GOD. THAT ACTUALLY WORKED. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please explain how that worked? Even though my text is commented?

Comment: Can you also please take a look at the end of webpage, the box is extended outside the background view, is there a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry I was away and is that how you want it to look like - https://jsfiddle.net/a2usgvtj/ or [full-screen demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a2usgvtj/show/) ?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to look! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put `text-align: center;` on `#aboutMeDescriptionItemList` to center the items inside it. Right now it has the default `text-align: left;`
2. There is no origin in a browser window, html elements just flow one after the other, sitting in the first place that offers enough room. Use `overflow: hidden;` on `.aboutMeDescriptionItem` to prevent the H3 (or anything else) to extend from inside the box.

Also note that putting the inline-block divs on separate lines of code will trigger a bug in Google Chrome that will create spaces between the boxes equal to a character space. In order to avoid that you can set `font-size: 0;` on the parent of inline-block elements and set the font size back to what you need it on the inline-block elements themselves. Chrome will still insert a space equal to the width of a character, but that is 0 at font-size: 0.

```css
#secondPageContainer {
    font-family: "San Francisco - Ultra Light";
    font-weight: 100;
    color: rgba(44, 62, 80,1.0);

    display: block;

    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 0;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh; 
}
#aboutMe {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#aboutMeTitle {
    font-size: 5em;
}
#aboutMeSubtitle {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
#aboutMeDescription {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
#aboutMeDescriptionBasic {
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96,1.0);
}

#aboutMeDescriptionBasic h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 25px;
}

#aboutMeDescriptionItemList {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.aboutMeDescriptionItem {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(39, 174, 96,1.0);
}
.aboutMeDescriptionItem h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="secondPageContainer">
        <div id="aboutMe">
            <h2 id="aboutMeTitle">About Me</h2>
            <h4 id="aboutMeSubtitle">Get to know me better</h4>
        </div>
    <div id="aboutMeDescription">
        <div id="aboutMeDescriptionBasic">
            <h3> Something about me... </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper">
            <div id="aboutMeDescriptionItemList">
                <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
                    <h3>bla bla.</h3> </div>
                <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
                    <h3>bla bla bla.</h3> </div>
                <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
                    <h3>Bla bla bla bla bla something really long.</h3></div>
                <div class="aboutMeDescriptionItem">
                    <h3>Bla bla bla bla bla something really even longer..</h3></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! But, `aboutMeDescriptionItemListWrapper` is extended outside the `secondPageContainer` when the browser window width is reduced; due to which one of the boxes is partially outside the background. How do I solve this?

Comment: You have to put `overflow: auto;` on the parent DIV so that margins from inline-block styled elements inside do not overflow outside of the container `#secondPageContainer`. Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/L2eryzxn/2/